# z-index not working right

Tags: html, css, z-index

Page in question:

http://meyers.ipalaces.org/sitemap/

The first `<LI>` should be `z-index: 2;` and should be on top of any other `<LI>` further down. (Meyers)

CSS:

```
.sitemap #primaryNav > ul > li {
    float: none;
    background: #ffffff url('images/L1-left.png') center bottom no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

The idea is that the background color of #fff should be ontop of the `<LI>`'s below, therefore creating an effect similar to this:

http://astuteo.com/slickmap/demo/

if you use firebug on the above link and disable `position:relative`
from `#primaryNav #home` You'll see that it looks like mine. I am not sure how to get it to be like theirs.

Comment: It may help to post the broken code instead of the code that works...

Comment: The code I posted is the "broken" code.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what is wrong (or in what browser)? Your example seems fine to me.

Comment: be sure to review the answers on your question and reward the bounty. Otherwise you've just wasted 50 rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Positioning and z-index won't be of any use, if the `<li>` you're trying to bring to the top layer is actually bringing the entire site map with it.*

Look at the source of your page side by side with Astuteo's code. There are a couple of places that you *REALLY* changed the markup:

```
Astuteo:     <ul id="primaryNav"> /* using natural block tags */
Meyers: <div id="primaryNav"><ul class="level--0"> /* wrapping without need */

Astuteo:      <li id="home"><a href....>Home</a></li> /* CLOSED li (immediately) */
*Meyers:  <li><a href...>Home</a>...the entire sitemap...</li> /* you wrapped the entire site map inside your first <li> */
```

Your desired solution essentially mirrors the original code. A rewrite or copy/paste at this point would probably be less time consuming than tracking down the remaining errors in syntax modification and/or layout strategy.

**EDIT**: have you tried something as simple as...removing the background property for the first-child of home?

```
<ul class="level--1">
    <li style="background: none">...
```

It would be something like this in your CSS (to keep your CSS out of your HTML):

```
.level--1 li:first-child { background:none; }
```

Comment: I did try closing that firt list-item, but it created more aesthetic issues than it solved.

Comment: Correct, I am trying to get their CSS to match the more standardized format that most PHP sitemap to UL generators create.

Comment: Was writing a post about z-index...and thought of a potential fix for you -- see edit above

Comment: Removing the background for the first-child worked. Simple solution. Don't know why I didn't think of it. Edit: seems to effect level 3 but step in right direction, i'll figure something out

Comment: What does background: none; do? Why on the first child?

Answer (score 8):

First thing I would point out is that, in your case, "home" is not the origin in the sitemap. While might want it to seem that way visually, semantically this is not the case. [SlickMap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/) understands this (or maybe they just got lucky), which is why in their html the "home" `li` is at the same level as the other primary pages. The only thing above other pages is the root, which has no page (though most people redirect root to the "homepage").

Second, once a parent's `z-index` is set, unless the child is set to `position: absolute` and the parent is *not* set to `position: relative`, all children are considered to *start* one level above the parent in regards to stacking order. This is defined in the CSS 2.1 standard under [9.9.1 Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) as (emphasis mine):

> The order in which the rendering tree is painted onto the canvas is described in terms of stacking contexts. **Stacking contexts can contain further stacking contexts**. A stacking context **is atomic from the point of view of its parent stacking context;** boxes in other stacking contexts may not come between any of its boxes.

So, while [SlickMap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/) was able to tell you:

> The first `<LI>` should be `z-index: 2;` and should be on top of any other `<LI>` further down.

In your design doing so makes no difference because moving the first `li` upwards moves all of it's children with it. And, since the children in your home block start their own stacking context one level higher than the parent, your "home" li can never be above the items inside it.

Now that that is out of the way. I reviewed your code with the [SlickMap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/) code to understand the differences. As you can see below, there is pretty much only one reasonable option here that is going to be 100% compatible.

`z-index` does support negative numbers but, since the stacking context is different between "home" and it's siblings, you cannot use that here. However, if each child of "home" was set to `position: absolute` and the "home" `li` was set to `position: static` (the default) you could, in some edge cases, use `z-index: -1` on those children and make them appear to be behind the parent. But, you have to have other variables available as well (such as the parent's parent's background being transparent) **AND**, most importantly, you would have to position each child manually. Clearly this is not a good idea. Not to mention negatives in `z-index` is buggy in IE6/7.

What you need to do is, as [SlickMap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/) did, merge the first `ul` under the `li` containing "home" with `ul.level--0`. This will result in the following hierarchy:

```
ul
--Home
--Meyers
    --Another Level
--M....
    --Another Level
--etc
```

Then, you should be able to apply `z-index: 2` to the "home" `li` and you will get the result you are looking for. Obviously, the change in structure will likely require other changes to your styles as well.

There are probably some ways that CSS 3 properties could help you, but I dont want to get into that as I'm unsure your requirements.

Hopefully this lesson in CSS layout strcutres was helpful enough for you to make an informed decision on how to move forward with your project. If you have any addition questions about what I've said, just let me know.

Comment: This is the most indepth answer. I would of rewarded this had Dawson not solve the problem so simplistically

Answer (score 1):

Well, it took a while to work out but I think I have it now. I must say that my Spidey sense was on high due to the fact that the page [does not validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmeyers.ipalaces.org%2Fsitemap%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

This is not really a z-index problem since you're using a 3rd party (and most excellent!) framework to style the HTML - [SlickMap CSS](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/) which should work as advertised.

The problem isn't with the invalid markup although that should be fixed regardless. Namely that there are missing `</li>` tags, there is an invalid `<br>` in the `utilityNav` and duplicate id attributes in the main `primaryNav`.

The problem is that you have introduced extra `<ul>` levels and the CSS rules just don't match the correct elements any more. Is this required for any reason? I can see that this has tried to be corrected by adding child selectors to your CSS, but the markup is radically different to what the framework expects and hence the z-index stacking isn't correct.

With a minimal `<ul>` [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2pw5K/) works as expected since the HTML is correct for the SlickMap CSS. So I'd try and remove the extra `<ul>` levels from your markup and mimic the markup on the [SlickMap demo page](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/demo/) or my fiddle.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah I am purposely modifying the slickmap css to actually allow for the UL design I gave it. The reason is that their example doesn't allow for easy sitemap.xml to UL. They have "home" which is basically the first level as apart of the 2nd level. I was hoping to to make it work more intuitively such as having the "home" be on its own level, as I think it should. I can modify my php code that converts the sitemap.xml to UL in order to accommodate for slickmap, but why should I? slickmap should accommodate for the more standardized format.

Comment: As far as validation, this is just a test-site and I just had the ID's there for my personal viewing, but you are right that should be classes. In order to help diagnose the problem,  I have fixed all validation errors by going to loose (which I should of had it anyways, until I convert to strict). The only thing thats not validate now is my `link` tag, and thats because its in a PHP template, the live/real site doesn't have this issue.

Comment: A valid structure will eliminate the browser "best guessing" which style to apply to which element which has caused problems for me in the past.

Comment: I agree that you can remove the "home" id and make things more generic but having played with your code and style I could only make it work by reverting to the SlickMap format. SlickMap site itself says that it is "accommodating up to three levels of page navigation" and you have more than that.

Comment: OK, so I've looked again at your HTML and because `position` is being applied to the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags you are creating a new stacking context each time. The layering only works [inside each context](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex). So I tried to get the stacking context correct on your markup with the extra `<ul>` tag and keeping "home" as its own level - [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2pw5K/1/). Is this any better?

Comment: The demo looks good, I noticed you had a </li> that didnt match a <li>. Perhaps you didnt mean to close the home's <li> so soon. I tried to do this without having the `UL` inside the `LI`..and then closing the `LI` as it should in strict. Results were not good when I started to include more than just the 2 levels: http://meyers.ipalaces.org/sitemap/index2.php

Comment: Perhaps it's my lack of css knowledge to actually apply the technique you are demoing beyond just the 2 levels of your demo. If you could get it to look right with all the levels, then you have solved it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I messed up the markup which was causing the hierarchy to display correctly. I think I have fixed the first level now with the "home" as a separate `<li>` - http://jsfiddle.net/2pw5K/3/ I will try and make the other levels work now.

Comment: Well, it feels like a massive hack but have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2pw5K/6/ and let me know what you think. The CSS is not very pretty and could definitely be more optimised, but it seems to be working for all the levels. I really would try and just use the SlickMap CSS as-is and re-generate your site map to conform with the existing structure since every level I came to style was more complex than than the last. Plus, I've only tested this in Chrome 11, so who knows how broken this might look in another browser :)

Answer (score 0):

The parent will need to have position relative to get a proper z-index stacking context. Super obscure, but maybe this will work for you?

Try reading through this link to get a better understanding of the (super obscure, no fault of yours) method of determining the stacking priority of DOM elements:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context

Comment: This is educational, but I still can't seem to get the z-index to work. Am I missing something? I have set every parent I could to `position: relative` and it wasn't making a different.

Comment: The element with `z-index` needs to be positioned. Parents have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Kind of what I was thinking, but the element is `position: relative` and the z-index is still not working?